# How to make an iframe responsive with responsiveiframes.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am testing  responsiveiframes.js to make an iframe responsive, the contest inside the iframe is not responsive.

How can i make it responsive? must the content in the iframe be responsive? is there other option to make an iframe responsive (jquery or something else)?

Thanks a lot.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <title>ResponsiveIframes.js</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Homepage CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />   
    <script src="http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/js/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/js/jquery.responsiveiframe.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body lang="en">

    <div class="hero-unit bg-noise">
            <h1>Responsive IFrames</h1>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () {
                $('iframe').responsiveIframe({xdomain: '*'});
            });
    </script><div class='row-fluid contentArea'>

        <div class='span8'>
        <div style='padding: 10px 0 10px 0; background-color: white;'>
            <iframe src='http://www.cuandoenelmundo.com/' style='width: 100%; height:1000px; padding: 0px;margin: 0; border: none; display: block; overflow: hidden;' />
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `height: auto` instead of `hieght: 1000px;` on iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get responsiveiframes.js to work myself but I gave up and wrote my own javascript plugin (https://github.com/jcharlesworthuk/reactive.iframes, example [here](http://jcharlesworthuk.github.io/reactive.iframes/example/index.html)).

Essentially, the content inside the iframe doesn't have to responsive per se, but it does have to communicate its height back to the parent so the height style can be set.  There really isn't any solution with just CSS if you can't control the height of the content inside the iframe.